# No spec files found when running Cypress using scripts in package.json

Tags: cypress

I am trying to use script aliases in the package.json file.

In order for something like this to open the test runner,

```
"cy:open:prod": "cypress open --env ENV=production",
```

I run the command `npm run cy:open:prod` in the command line in the same folder that package.json is located.

The script runs and opens the test runner, however no spec files are found.

In all the examples I have found it describes this approach. Is there something I am missing in configuation to point it to where my spec files are?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of cypress..? Can you please share you `cypress.config.js` file if you are on Cypress v10+ above ..

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing basically wrong with the scripts in package.json, they look normal and would not cause the problem you mention.

I suggest you check the `specPattern` setting in configuration, it should match the naming convention you have chosen to use for your specs.

See [e2e settings](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e) for more details.

Of you still have trouble with it, start a new project and let Cypress set the configuration for you, it will automatically match up the specPattern to the default value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The spec patterns are correct. If I run: npx cypress open from the same folder location as my specs they show up with no problem. The issue is that the only way to run the npm script is from where package.json is located. And no specs are found because there are no specs in that location.

Comment: Normally you run `npx cypress open` from the project root - did you try that? Maybe it's just project structure, but just having to guess as you're a bit thin on details :)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. It was related to my folder structure. Working great now! Not sure how I messed that up ;)